# How do resize/scale python Seaborn barplot chart?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Using a filtered dataset that dealt with leading cause of death in the US (https://storage.googleapis.com/hewwo/NCHS_-_Leading_Causes_of_Death__United_States.csv), I wrote the following code:

```
`sns.barplot(x="state", y="deaths", hue="cause_name", data=death_filtered_smoking,).set_title("Cancer 
and Heart Disease Deaths by State (2011)")`
```

While this technically does what I want it too, the resulting graph looks like this: [image: Barplot Result]

How can I resize this chart (mostly increasing width) so that it's readable? Anything I try from my own reaserach involving height, width, and aspect give me errors, or simply do nothing.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're doing this on Jupyter, just drag along the cell output area to create a box on the chart, which will zoom into that area.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving it to a file  to get the desired resolution
sns_plot.savefig("output.png")